# How can I force systemd service to start at boot

Tags: systemd, watchdog

Apologies if I am missing details, I may not be aware of all the areas on systemd
I am trying to make my phosphor-watchdog service start automatically after another service, I cannot understand why it is by default disabled.

```
> /lib/systemd/system# ls |grep phosphor-watchdog
>
> phosphor-watchdog@.service
>
> phosphor-watchdog@poweron.service.d

/lib/systemd/system# systemctl status phosphor-watchdog@poweron.service
● phosphor-watchdog@poweron.service - Phosphor poweron watchdog
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/phosphor-watchdog@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/phosphor-watchdog@poweron.service.d
             └─poweron.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

this is the service file for phosphor-watchdog service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Phosphor %I watchdog
Conflicts=host-force-poweroff@0.service
After=pwr-monitor.service

[Service]
Restart=always
EnvironmentFile={envfiledir}/obmc/watchdog/%I
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env phosphor-watchdog --continue --service=${{SERVICE}} --path=${{DEVPATH}} --target=${{TARGET}}
SyslogIdentifier=phosphor-watchdog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and for phosphor-watchdog@poweron.service.d/poweron.conf:

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=obmc-host-stop@0.target
Conflicts=obmc-chassis-poweroff@0.target
Conflicts=obmc-host-quiesce@0.target
```

I am wondering why is my service always disabled despite the presence of "WantedBy=multi-user.target"

FYI: with systemctl enable everything works fine, but I want it to be enabled by default.

please let me know if I need to give further information.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Per [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#%5BInstall%5D%20Section%20Options):

> [Install] is not interpreted by systemd(1) during runtime; it is used by the enable and disable commands of the systemctl(1) tool during installation of a unit.

Therefore anything appearing in the `[Install]` section will have no effect unless you use `systemctl enable`.

> FYI: with systemctl enable everything works fine,

This is the intended behaviour.  `systemctl enable` will add a persistent symbolic link so every boot between now, and when it is disabled will cause the unit to trigger.

> but I want it to be enabled by default.

Installation is more than copying a file.  Typically a package will:

1. Install the service to `/lib/systemd/system/`
2. `systemctl enable` the service
3. `systemctl start` the service

So part of your installation should be the `systemctl enable`.

---

I recall in systemd's early days, there were lots of people who didn't want services to be enabled by default.  Arch packages, for example, did not `enable`/`start` services by default.

In Debian, there is a helper called `deb-systemd-helper` which is used by packages instead of calling `systemctl enable` directly.  It does things like decide whether to `enable` a unit based on the `vendor preset` (yours is enabled) while respecting your decisions if you explicitly disabled/masked it before an upgrade.  It also does some other handy things like reset/reload units when they get updated, or stop units before uninstalling them.